# Python Numpy array equality failure

Tags: python, numpy

Why does this fail? I create an array, create a new variable with that array minus a value from within the array, and then compare the array to a value that *appears* to be in the array. So why does the equality test fail?

```
import numpy as np
import platform
print platform.python_version()
print np.__version__ 
x = np.arange( -1,1,0.1 )
new_x = x - x[5]
print new_x
print new_x == -0.2
```

outputs:

```
2.7.9
1.9.2
[-0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9  1.   1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4]
[False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False]
```

EDIT: 
Using np.round() causes the comparison to behave as expected; the question now is, why am I being presented with rounded numbers when I print the array? In my experience python will usually print scientific notation or just a bunch of decimal places when the numbers are not exact.

Shockingly, I have been programming in python scientifically for 6 years and never seen this! It feels like a noob question but I really don't understand why what's printed is rounded.

Comment: I just tested, and np.linspace() behaves the same way. I am assuming this is a precision thing but it would be nice to know exactly why it's happening.

Comment: Try `print np.round(new_x, decimals=1) == -0.2`

Comment: Thanks Scott, that works. In the past I've always noticed that numbers that are not exact are printed in scientific notation. So why am I getting rounded numbers printed but not in the comparison? That's really what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: I don't know the answer as to why, but it seems due to floating point precision.

Comment: Scott, definitely >>> x[12]    yields   0.19999999999999973     >>> x[12] - 0.2   yields
-2.7755575615628914e

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm hoping someone will explain why; I'm also curious.

Comment: For me, printing x[12] in the script prints exactly 0.2

Comment: It looks like by default, numpy will round to 8 digits when printing: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html

Comment: This is interesting, try `np.set_printoptions(precision=25)` just below your import, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html.  So yeah, it's most likely numpy's `ndarray.__str__`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python has some usefule ideas... particularly        np.isclose(x[12], 0.2, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=False)   a bit of overkill for two numbers but useful otherwise  Scott ... do a search using "Floating point representation" to find out why with examples

Answer (score 3):

As you suspect, the strange behavior is due to small precision errors that occur during the floating point calculations. To see the differences, you can convert the floats into a hexadecimal form using [`float.hex()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.hex):

```
>>> new_x[3].hex()
'-0x1.9999999999998p-3'
>>> (-0.2).hex()
'-0x1.999999999999ap-3'
```

Notice that they are, in fact, two different floating point numbers. The "rounding" only occurs while printing, and is in fact something that [Python itself does by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16112798/716118). The basic idea is that there are two forms of string representations for Python objects (including floats): `str` and `repr`. Whereas `repr` should return an "authentic", reproducible string representation, `str` should optimize for human-readability - and part of that includes "rounding", to hide small precision errors. Notice:

```
>>> repr(new_x[3])
'-0.19999999999999996'
>>> repr(-0.2)
'-0.2'
```

For floats, you can simulate an equality check using [`numpy.isclose()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html), like so:

```
>>> print numpy.isclose(new_x, -0.2)
[False False False  True False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False]
```

Comment: When calling `repr(new_x)` each value within the numpy array is rounded.  Seems inconsistent.  Any idea why this was chosen over an array where each value is the full repr value?

Comment: @Scott: Hmm, that *is* odd. Unfortunately, I don't know why this is the case. You can always [submit a ticket](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues) about it.