# python floating point, why is the print result different (examples given)?

Tags: list, printing, floating-point, tuples, precision

a = (random.random(), random.random())

print(a)

print(a[0])

the result is:

> > > (0.4817527913069962, 0.7017598562799067)
> > >
> > > 0.481752791307

What extra is happening behind printing a tuple(similar behavior for list)? Why is there extra fraction?

Thanks a lot.

BTW, this is python 2.7

Comment: Duplicate of many, including this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105833/python-strangely-rounding-values/16112798#16112798

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is the difference between the formatting choices made by `str(float)` and `repr(float)`. In Python 2.x, `str(float)` returns 12 digits while `repr(float)` returns 17 digits. In its interactive mode, Python uses `str()` to format the result. That accounts for the 12 digits of precision when formatting a float. But when the result is a tuple or list, the string formatting logic uses `repr()` to format each element.

The output of `repr(float)` must be able to be converted back to the original value. Using 17 digits of precision guarantees that behavior. Python 3 uses a more sophisticated algorithm that returns the shortest string that will round-trip back to the original value. Since `repr(float)` frequently returns a more friendly appearing result, `str(float)` was changed to be the same as `repr(float)`.

Comment: BTW, Python 2.7 uses the same algorithm for float `repr` as Python 3 does. It's only Python 2.6 and earlier that construct a repr based on 17 significant digits.